# how to minimize the effect of space or newline in HTML?

Tags: html, newline, doctype, spaces

First of all, my question may be unclear. I will try to explain it.

this is my html

```
<div class="left"><?php print $search_box; ?><?php if (!empty($logo)): ?><a href="<?php print $base_path; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" id="logo" width="243" height="62" /></a><?php endif; ?><?php if (!empty($site_name)): ?><div id='site-name'><strong><a href="<?php print $base_path; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home"><?php print $site_name; ?></a></strong></div><?php endif; ?><?php if (!empty($site_slogan)): ?><div id='site-slogan'><?php print $site_slogan; ?></div><?php endif; ?></div>
```

looks ugly and difficult to debug, right?

so i try to indent and add newline. However, it will fails on some browser, may be IE6. The result is changed. So, What should i go, should i use another doctype?

Currently, i am using

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Comment: Try to nicely indent the code and instead of ending the php block to add the HTML, try to `$echo` the HTML and see if that works better. If you need me to clarify, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it this way too:

```
<div class="left">
  <?php print $search_box; ?>
    <?php if (!empty($logo)) { ?>
    <a href="<?php print $base_path; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home">
      <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" id="logo" width="243" height="62" />
    </a>
  <?php } ?>

  <?php if (!empty($site_name)) { ?>
    <div id='site-name'>
      <strong>
      <a href="<?php print $base_path; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home"><?php print $site_name; ?></a>
      </strong>
    </div>
  <?php } ?>

  <?php if (!empty($site_slogan)) { ?>
    <div id='site-slogan'><?php print $site_slogan; ?></div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

This should work in most cases, or you can use the [php heredoc syntax](http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-heredoc-syntax.html) to echo out the html stuff normally.

Comment: um... are you sure replacing : with { solve the problem??
Actually i want to do exactly what u wrote. however, IE will change the output, because there is extra #text nodes inside the tags.

new browser don't have this problem.

Comment: or you may try using the heredoc syntax of php, see my answer again. thanks

Comment: My IE6 VM is dead, so i cannot test this. but heredoc is great, thanks for the help.